# How to export XML from excel with not exportable error?

Tags: excel, xml, export

I tried to export excel table into xml file. But am getting an error that the xml maps in this workbook are not exportable.

[image]

I have attached the excel file and the xml which i am using to create mapping.
Thank you in advance

[Files Link][2]
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17gX8LuhEye3K6ido8qvDF9sREkc0Ggw0?usp=sharing

Comment: Try menu File : SaveAs  and select XML as the type.

Comment: @jdweng not working, can you please elaborate more.

Comment: The File SAVEAS menu has XML on the pulldown.  What is not working?